# Can I specify a different 'extends' base template in Python when using Jinja 2?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using Jinja as a standalone library in a script so that I can write multiple versions of a website, one using base_a.html and the other using base_b.html, base_c.html and so on.

The `extends` keyword used in the files however requires the base template name to be specified in each of the child remplates.

Is there a way to specify the base template name in Python, something like

`t.render(extends="base_a.html")`

for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is a way to do this,

Use the following as your `extends` tag in the child templates,

```
 {% extends base_template %}
```

Then use the following,

```
from jinja2 import Environment, Template, FileSystemLoader
env = Environment(loader = FileSystemLoader(["../templatedir"])
t = env.get_template("child.html")
print t.render(base_template="parent_template.html")
```

Comment: Yup! That's exactly what I do, except I wrap the `{% extends template %}` inside `{% if template %}` and `{% endif %}`, as it'll die without a valid argument to `extends`.